# Need total sum for users in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table.

```
    Result1         
ID  PT  IT  CC  I_user  D_user
123 10  1   1   ABC      ABC
256 20  5   2   xyz      ABC
389 15  2   5   SRT      xyz
522 20  3   1   ABC      SRT
655 10  2   4   xyz      ABC
788 20  1   3   SRT      xyz
921 15  5   2   ABC      SRT
105 10  4   4   xyz      ABC
```

Desired result set from the query

```
User  PT      IT    CC
ABC   85      20    14
xyz   75      14    18
SRT   70      11    11
```

Any help is appreciated. I am using google sql but I think,standard sql will also work..

Comment: Please explain the logic for the transformation.  You should tag the database you are using.  "standard sql" is not really supported fully by any database.

Comment: Simple Group by on I_USER .

Comment: What is your question here, you haven't asked one. What have you tried to solve the problem *yourself*? What RDBMS are you *actually* using, as you tagged SQL Server, MySQL and Big Query (all very different products). Please take the time to edit your question, show your attempts and research and retag the **correct** RDBMS.

Comment: @Shubh Look again, there is no way to reach the expected result when doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the aggregated totals of PT, IT, CC per user that's either in I_user or D_user.

In that case you could simply use a UNION with queries that group on I_user or D_user.

```
SELECT "User", SUM(PT) AS PT,  SUM(IT) AS IT,  SUM(CC) AS CC
FROM
(
    SELECT I_user as "User", SUM(PT) AS PT,  SUM(IT) AS IT,  SUM(CC) AS CC
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY I_user

    UNION ALL

    SELECT D_user, SUM(PT),  SUM(IT),  SUM(CC)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (D_user != I_user OR I_user IS NULL)
    GROUP BY D_user
) AS q
GROUP BY "User"
ORDER BY "User";
```

Comment: @lukstroms, Thanks. you are correct. Let me validate.

Comment: @lukstroms, The problem is if the user is both in I_user and D_user, the query adding the PT,IT,CC 2 times.

Comment: @syncdm2012  Updated.  Now in the second unioned query it doesn't SUM those where the D_user equals the I_user.  So then the values are only summed once.

Comment: Thank a ton LukStorms.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using a lateral join and aggregation:

```
select v.user, sum(t.pt) as pt, sum(t.it) as it, sum(t.cc) as cc
from t cross apply
     (values (t.I_user), (t.D_user)) v(user)
group by v.user;
```

Comment: Thank you @gordon Linoff. Truly appreciate for quick response